# Limiting the number of Instagram Photos with API call on website

Tags: instagram, photos

I'm trying to build a simple webpage that displays a collage of pictures from our instagram account.  I'm currently pulling the photos via the ajax call below.

$(".instagram2").instagram({
            userId: '2675945',
            clientId: '1ac753e7b7456798fe8087381ec5678',
            image_size: 'standard_resolution',
        });

What I'm trying to accomplish is to pull only to first 10 photos that will be displayed in the first DIV tag and have the rest displayed in the 2nd DIV tag. The 2nd DIV should show photos 11  - max allowed by API.  I'm not sure how to have the 2nd DIV display photos starting at #11.  I'm using c#.  Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily limit photos by doing it within your loop. For example, pretend you have a method called printPhotos. Below, I'm counting the iterations and limiting photos based on this.

```
var i = 0;
function printPhotos(){
    if( $i < 10 ){
        // RENDER INSTAGRAM PHOTO HERE
    }
    i++;
}
```